# Where can I find reference for urxvt .Xresources config options?

Tags: urxvt

I'm trying to configure urxvt, running Arch and xfce, but can seem to find a list of all aviable .Xresources urxvt configuration options anywhere.
Where can I find one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official rxvt-unicode man page has a resources section which covers that, I believe:
http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/doc/rxvt.1.pod#RESOURCES

Answer (score 1):

There's also a nice resource on the ArchWiki which includes some example entries:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode#Creating_.7E.2F.Xresources