# how to get/print all urxvt options/settings/variables

Tags: x-server, urxvt

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/265487/180675) tells, where to find a reference for urxvt .Xresources config options.

I have [found this command](http://www.askapache.com/linux/rxvt-xresources.html#rxvt_Resources_descriptions) to print the entire rxvt resources with descriptions taken from the manpage with its default values:

```
man -Pcat urxvt | sed -n '/th: b/,/^B/p'|sed '$d'|sed '/^ \{7\}[a-z]/s/^ */^/g' | sed -e :a -e 'N;s/\n/@@/g;ta;P;D' | sed 's,\^\([^@]\+\)@*[\t ]*\([^\^]\+\),! \2\n! URxvt*\1\n\n,g' | sed 's,@@\(  \+\),\n\1,g' | sed 's,@*$,,g' | sed '/^[^!]/d' | tr -d "'\`"
```

But how can I print or somehow get **the current values** for these settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings for X programs can be stored in the X resource database. You can interact with that database via the `xrdb` utility, see `man xrdb` for details.

So, to get the current setting for `URxvt`, use the `-query` option:

```
xrdb -query | grep -i urxvt
```

You will get a list of the options explicitly defined in your `~/.Xresources` for example. All other options will probably use the default value, which you already extracted from the man page.